# Notification in django rest API

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-notification

I want to make a notification system in django so that, when you add a new entry to the database I get notified. As admin I do everything in the Django Rest API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.rooms.room_bool = instance.room_bool
        instance.rooms.save()
        token = '5419477:AAHuyagslasglfsE9O-90vgiDHVTiV2KmqFRNw'
        URL = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + token + '/sendMessage'
        for chat_id in ADMINS:
            try:
                data = {'chat_id': chat_id, 'text': "Забронирован один номер через Ресепшен\n\n"
                                                    "Посмотрите по ссылке http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/reg_admin/registration/\n\n"
                                                    "Нажмите /start чтобы вывести меню администратора"}
                requests.post(URL, data=data)
            except Exception:
                pass
```

using signals.py, I sent a message to the bot via json

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you want the admin to be contacted. I'm going to assume you already have a model, a [view](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/) and a [serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/) (preferably a **ModelSerializer**) inside your Django app. If not, take a look over the links I've sent to you.

At this moment, I'm thinking about contacting the admin of the system in two ways: 1.) by sending an email to the administrator of the system or 2.) by creating an object of type "Notification" (or named hovewer you want), which the admin can inspect from the panel.

For the first option, you can just override one of the REST serializer's methods (preferably [create()](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances)). **create()** is the actual method that gets called after you specify the fields for your model before sending a POST request to create it. You can add some **send_email()** method inside your **create()**, containing some of the validated data. [send_email()](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-save-directly) is also mentioned inside REST's documentation (exactly at the Serializing section), but I'm not sure it helps that much. You can check up its proper syntax by just googling it.

The second way would be by just creating a new model (called **Notification**? maybe) and add a new entry inside the database, everytime a request of object creation is made (so you'll basically still need to override the **create()** method inside your serializer). You can also add a field (boolean? maybe) called **isRead**, which the admin can mark as true/false. If any notifications with **isRead ==  false** are found, they'll appear on the admin's page.

Comment: is it possible to implement this through a telegram bot
for example, when a new entry is added to the database so that the notification does not come through the mail, but through the telegram bot on the aiogram

Comment: and if you can show a piece of such code please